# Laravel 6 relationship output as array not object

Tags: laravel

The laravel 6.x returns the output as an array instead of an object when accessing the relationship in one pc it supports the array and on the other pc, it only supports the object.

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'parent_id');
    }

    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'parent_id');
    }

}
```

on the blade page this can be accessed like below

```
 @foreach ($categories as $category)
   <tr>

     <td >{{$category->parent['name']}}</td>
   </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: In my laravel (6 too) it's not happen, try to use "get()" method from any of the methods above and see what's happen, if is an array will return an error, if not return an error so it's means that the new version of laravel don't depend of the "get()" method anymore.

Comment: `$category->parent->name` and `$category->parent['name']` are both valid in Laravel; Models are accessible via either syntax, but the preferred method is object access (`->`).

Comment: @TimLewis,  Do you know the reason for these two type of different issues. How to change the array to object?

Comment: Like the answer says below, it's *not* an array, unless you call `->toArray()`. I've never seen the issue with one method of access `->name` not working vs the other `['name']`.

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent models implement [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

So `$category->parent->name` should work the same as `$category->parent['name']`.

It's not actually an array it just is accessible like one.